# How to extract the data on hourly basis using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the dataframe in which data is minute basis like shown below:

```
           Date               Open    High    Low     Close 
0   01.01.2015 00:00:00.000 1.20976 1.20976 1.20976 1.20976 0.0
1   01.01.2015 00:01:00.000 1.20976 1.20976 1.20976 1.20976 0.0
2   01.01.2015 00:02:00.000 1.20976 1.20976 1.20976 1.20976 0.0
```

As you can see there is `12:01, 12:02....` I do not need the data like this , I expect only hourly basis like `12:00, 13:00, 14:00` etc.
How can I do this ?

Comment: Extract `hour` from `Date` column in all rows, `group` on `Date` & `hour`, `sum` the remaining columns.

Comment: Can you please post your code

Comment: Do you just want to delete the other rows?

Comment: Yes, I do not want to retain other rows

Comment: What do you want to do with the extra data? Throw it out? Sum? Average? Something else? Do you want the hourly timestamps to reflect what happened during that hour, or are you only interested in the values specifically at the top of each hour?

Comment: throw it out, as i just want to retain data which is of hourly basis only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) # You may not need to do this.

df = df[df['Date'].dt.minute == 0]
```

Comment: What about `01.01.2015 00:00:15.123` ;)

Comment: Haha, good point!

Comment: hahah no need to retain

Comment: @richardec How can I convert this string '20030505' to 2003-05-05

Comment: @stackoverflow `pd.to_datetime('20030505')`

Comment: Don't let Pandas infer the date if there are ambiguities...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DatetimeIndex.floor`, assuming `Date` column has already `datetime64` dtype:

```
>>> df[df['Date'] == df['Date'].dt.floor('H')]
        Date     Open     High      Low        Close
0 2015-01-01  1.20976  1.20976  1.20976  1.20976 0.0
```

> How can I convert this string '20030505 01:00:00.000'

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%d%m %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Comment: How can I convert this string '20030505' to 2003-05-05